# ¿Como sumar cantidad ingresadas en un input generado dinamicamente, jquery?

Tags: jquery

la lista dinamica es generada de la siguiente forma:

```
var listado_facturas = $('.listado_facturas');
$.each(response.data, function (index, value) {
$('<tr/>')
    .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(value.NumeroDocumento))
     /*.append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(value.Fecha))  */      
    .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(value.Cod_Cliente))        
    .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(moneda(value.Total)))
    .append('<div class="numero_documento" style="display:none">' + value.NumeroDocumento + '</div>')        
    .append($('<td style=" padding-right: 10px; border-right-width: 10px; padding-left: 10px;"/>').addClass('label-cell classCantidad derecha')
    .append('<input type="text" style="width: 100%; font-size: 12px;" step="0.01" name="cantidad" class="cantidad" attr-num-doc="' + value.NumeroDocumento + '" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" placeholder="Monto">'))
    .appendTo(listado_facturas);
})
```

Estoy sumando los valores al ingresar a un input `cantidad`
de la siguiente forma:

```
var total_pago_traslado;
    $('.listado_facturas').on('change', '.cantidad', function(e){
        let  factura = $(this).closest('tr');
        let numero_documento = factura.find('.numero_documento').text();
        let cantidad_ingresada = factura.find('.cantidad').val().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");


        var dejar = false;
        console.log(parseFloat(factura.find('.cantidad').val()));
        total_pago_traslado += parseFloat(factura.find('.cantidad').val());
        console.log(total_pago_traslado);
});
```

pero el resultado en la linea `console.log(parseFloat(factura.find('.cantidad').val()));` si es numerico por ejemplo (10), pero en la linea `console.log(total_pago_traslado);`me devuelve NaN.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: `E.target` para hacer referencia al elemento cambiado  dale console.log(this) y mira lo que devuelve, luego console.log(e.target) o solo e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El fallo lo tienes en la declaración de la variable var `total_pago_traslado;`.

Si no inicias la variable (en 0 por ejemplo ), no puedes utilizar la operación de `+=` ya que le estás añadiendo un valor a otro valor `NaN`.

La solución es tan sencilla como iniciar la variable, por ejemplo:

```
var total_pago_traslado = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ese código te sumará el valor del campo *cada vez que lo cambies*. Deberías sumar todos los valores cada vez:

```
var total_pago_traslado;

var sum_cancidades = function () {
    var total = 0;
    // puedes pasar un argumento a la función para filtrar
    // por una factura específica en vez de '.listado_facturas'
    $('.listado_facturas .cantidad').each( function () {
        // puedes limpiar el valor del campo aquí si quieres
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    } );
    console.log('total:', total);

};

total_pago_traslado = sum_cancidades();

$(document).on('change', '.listado_facturas .cantidad', function(e) {
    total_pago_traslado = sum_cancidades();
});
```